# Can I control which rules 'tslint --fix' auto fixes?

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

Is it possible to control which rules are auto-fixed when running `tslint --fix`? Ideally, I only want to autofix the whitespace and quotation rules, and I'll evaluate the rest manually. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation telling me which rules auto fix, or how to control which rules to apply though, and I'm a bit apprehensive about blindly fixing everything.

I'm currently using the tslint file that's autogenerated by Angular CLI.

Comment: I think you are right to be afraid, some fixes can indeed break your existing code (for instance, the rules concerning the 'don't use `null` use `undefined` instead' and likewise with `==` vs `===`.

Comment: To evaluate, I rely on my source-control to see the changes, for the rules, use a tslint.json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always run `tslint --fix` using a separate `tslint.json` file that contains only the rules you want to fix.  I believe the rules that auto-fix are the ones marked "Has Fixer" in the [list](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/).

Comment: I added to my NPM - "lint:one-rule-fix": "tslint -c tslint-empty.json src/**/*.ts --fix", and I specify one rule at a time there; (note - for eslint there was https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble , I wonder if something like this exists for tslint)

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you can use you own tslint.json, with your custom rules.

For the "evaluation" part of your problem, I suggest simply using your source-control. For instance, it's easy with Git to validate / discard changes by files, or even by lines / chunk.